# C++ pointers dynamic arrays and functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

This is from a beginning C++ class, no grade involved since I'm simply following along trying to remember stuff after too many years. The class has reached the point where we're using pointers and dynamic arrays. I'm trying to pass the array (or the pointer) to different functions having to do with various calculations on a list of integers. Some of the functions are working and others aren't. But I'm passing them all the same way and I'm calling them all the same way as well. Since some of the functions are returning garbage values, it feels like I'm not actually pointing where I think I am AND the functions that are working are only working by accident.

Before someone helpfully suggests that I should be using vectors and not arrays, the point of the exercise is to use dynamically allocated arrays.

Here's my code so far. It's the `findavg()` and `findmedian()` that are returning garbage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void getarray(int *a, int &l)
{
    int input = 0;

    //-1 is not important here, just to make the while loop run
    while(input != '-1') 
    {
        cout << "Enter length of the list of numbers: ";

        if(!(cin >> input))
        {
            cout << "Please enter numeric characters only." << "\n";    
            //show error if they don't enter a number
            cin.clear();                                                
            //get rid of invalid characters
            cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
        }

        else if(input <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number greater than 0." << "\n";    
            //show error if they enter a non-positive number
            cin.clear();                                                
            //get rid of invalid characters
            cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
        }
        else
        {
            l = input;  //input is a positive number
            break; //got good input, break out of while loop
        }

    }


    int i;
    int x; 

    cout << "Enter " << l << " integers on one line seperated by spaces.\n";


    for( i = 0; i < l  &&  cin >> x; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = x;
    }

}

void printarray(int *a, int &l)
{
    int i;

    cout << "The array of integers is:\n";
    for( i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        cout << setw(4) << a[i];
    cout << "\n";

}

int findmin(int *a, int &l)
{
    int min = 0;
    min = a[0]; 

    for(int i = 1; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] < min)
            min = a[i];
    }
    return min; 
}

int findmax(int *a, int &l)
{
    int max = 0;
    max = a[0];

    for(int i = 1; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > max)
            max = a[i];
    }
    return max; 
}

float findavg(int *a, int &l)
{
    int total = 0;
    total = a[0];

    for(int i = 1; i<l; i++)
    {
        total = total + a[i];
    }

    return static_cast<float>(total/static_cast<float>(l));

}

float findmedian(int *a, int &l)
{
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;

    max = findmax(a, l);
    min = findmin(a, l);

    return static_cast<float>((max + min)/2.0);

}


int main()
{

    int length = 0;
    int *an_array;

    an_array = new int[length];

    getarray(an_array, length);

    printarray(an_array, length);

    cout << "Maximum value in list is: "<< findmax(an_array, length) << "\n";
    cout << "Minimum value in list is: "<< findmin(an_array, length) << "\n";
    printf("Average is: %10.5f", findavg(an_array, length));
    cout << "\n";
    printf("Median is: %10.5f", findmedian(an_array, length));
    cout << "\n";

    delete [] an_array;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you learn about `std::vector` et. al. yet or did your professor start with dynamic arrays?

Comment: I don't think [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) means what you think it means.

Comment: `length` is always 0 when allocating memory for array!! You need to allocate memory in `getarray`

Comment: Already did an exercise with std::vector. For this drill we've been told specifically to NOT use vectors.

Comment: @John: Good, atleast your C++ course isn't rubbish, as many just start with dynamic arrays et. al. before even showing the standard library. :)

Comment: Ooops -- you're right. I'll need to correct that function and call it on the sorted array. I better "fix" what's going on with the references before I do that though.

Comment: And one more thing, why the printf in middle of cout? Look odd :P and you should ideally include <cstdio> to use printf

Comment: @another.anon.coward: ahhhhh, I need to move the line: `an_array = new int[length];` into `getarray();` as `a = new int[length];`

Comment: @another.anon.coward the `printf()` is to control the number of decimal places the avg displays, since it's a float. Once I correct my median function that will be returning an int and won't need the printf().

Comment: You can use [`setprecision`/`fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/) for that :)

Comment: @john please remember to accept the best answer, nawaz's in my view. Have a read of the [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int length = 0;
int *an_array;

an_array = new int[length]; //What is this ?
```

You're allocating zero bytes for `an_array`, because `length` is `0`. That is one problem I can see.

You should allocate memory for `an_array` in `getarray` function, after reading the length of array:

```
void getarray(int * &a, int &l) //see the change here!
{
    //code which reads length is omitted for brevity

    a = new int[l]; //alllocate memory after reading length

    //now read array elements here
}
```

---

Alternatively,you can write a struct as:

```
struct array
{
      int *data;
      size_t size;
};
```

And then use this everywhere. It is better because you tied the `size` and `data` together, and instead of using two independent objects, you can use just one object of type `array`, as described below.

```
array getarray() 
{
    array arr;

    //read length into arr.size

    arr.data= new int[arr.size]; //alllocate memory after reading length

    //now read array elements into arr.data

    return arr; //returning arr means you're returning both: data and size!
}
```

And then call this as:

```
 array arr = getarray(); //no need to pass any argument!
```

Also, if you're going to use this, then other functions signature would become:

```
void printarray(array arr);
int findmax(array arr);
float findavg(array arr);
float findmedian(array arr);
```

Now you need to modify these functions as well, but fortunately, there will not be major change : wherever you're using `a` and `l`, use `arr.data` and `arr.size` respectively instead. And you're done!

With all these improvements, your `main()` would become this:

```
int main()
{
    array arr = getarray();

    printarray(arr);

    cout << "Maximum value in list is: "<< findmax(arr) << "\n";
    cout << "Minimum value in list is: "<< findmin(arr) << "\n";

    printf("Average is: %10.5f\n", findavg(arr));
    printf("Median is: %10.5f\n", findmedian(arr));

    delete [] arr.data;
    return 0;
}
```

This looks better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- combining your points with everyone else's comments should get me there.

Comment: @JohnMcDermon: Now, see how `main()` looks like!

Comment: I like it. I'll have to give it a try and see how it affects things when I implement the correct `getmedian()` and then the `sort()` functions. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnMcDermon: There is no major change in those functions as well. For example, wherever you're using `a` and `l`, use `arr.data` and `arr.size` respectively instead.

Comment: @Nawaz: Do you think it will be a good idea to allocate & release memory as part of ctor & dtor of the structure so that its ok to forget `delete []` in the `main()`?  Or am I missing something in regard to this?

Comment: @another.anon.coward: That is definitely a good idea, popularly known as RAII, which is a different animal altogether. I didn't consider it here, because i didn't make `array` a resource-managing class, because for that I've to implement and explain copy-semantics as well. Also, I came up with a solution, which requires minimal change in OP's original code.

Comment: implemented @Nawaz suggestions and @David's use of `float` for the `getavg()` function. It all worked beautifully. Now on the the meat of the problem -- the sort algorithm and proper calculation of the median.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating any memory for the array. Undefined behaviour ensues.

Change your getarray function to do the allocate and *return* the newly created and populated array:

```
int* getarray(int &length)
```

or even

```
void AllocateAndPopulateArray(int* &array, int &length)
```

for a more symmetrical interface.

If you want a non-terminating loop use

```
while(true)
```

There is no need to bring input into your while loop.

There's no point passing the length by reference in any of the other routines since you are not modifying it. In fact you are asking for trouble passing by reference since a coding error may inadvertently change the value. You should declare it with const to make the compiler catch any silly mistakes you might make.

I most heartily agree with Nawaz's suggestion to tie together the pointer and length variables.

In your average calculation I personally would declare total to be a float and thus avoid the awkward looking casts.

Your implementation of median is plain wrong, but that seems to be a side issue.

Comment: Thanks David I see everything you pointed out. Certainly feel foolish about the error in getmedian() -- it's been too long :(  One thing, when I wasn't using the static_cast I was only getting integer results for getavg(). Not sure why, if the compiler is supposed to promote it to a float -- maybe it didn't since l is an int and I can't add a decimal place to induce floating point math without the cast?

Comment: That's my mistake. I misread in a hurry. I assumed total was a float. That's how I would have done it. Should not have assumed.

Comment: Ahhhh, but you bring up a good point -- I should declare total as a float and then I'd avoid the cast. I like it :)